# How to install Bootstrap on a chromebook?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Hence the title, how would I install Bootstrap on a chromebook? I researched on the net, but couldn't find a thing. Also on SO there doesn't seem to be a question that covers this topic. I tried using npm, but the commands from [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/) aren't working.

I have already created a website (although it is based on a theme, it is [totalnfl.com](http://totalnfl.com/)) and am looking to install Bootstrap to make my life easier when completely recoding it all from scratch (or maybe based on the old version, I'm not sure yet). Thanks!

Comment: just go to the bootstrap website and click download bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ , not need to use the terminal or anything.

Comment: But I can't _install_ it, it's not a problem with _downloading_ it.

Comment: @Christophvh I revised the question. Thanks!

Comment: @TotalNFL What do you mean by `install? Just add the script and link tags in your html

Comment: I guess I just didn't understand the "install" part. Thanks @giannisf, you answered my question!!! And thanks for upvoting it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything special in using a Chromebook because Bootstrap is a CSS/js framework.

You just download or use a CDN for the library and add the script and link tags in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can just directly link to bootstrap instead of downloading it

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
```